# Run minecraft from script in cronjob

Tags: cron

I tried making this command run at 10:20pm and then the second at 10:21pm
but nothing works. I tried as `root` and as `minecraft` user but nothing.
How can I get it to work?

```
20 10 * * * screen -S classic -p 0 -X stuff "stop^M"
21 10 * * * screen -S classic -d -m sh -c 'bash /home/minecraft/classic/.start.sh'
```

I even did something like this:

```
screen -S classic -X stuff "say crontab test"
```

to send on to minecraft as a console and broadcast, but I got nothing.

Comment: Try `DISPLAY=:0` before the commands...

Answer (score 1):

Those `cron` table entries are scheduled for 10:20 and 10:21 AM; not PM.  `cron` uses a 24-hour clock.  You probably want:

```
20 22 * * * screen -S classic -p 0 -X stuff "stop^M"
21 22 * * * screen -S classic -d -m sh -c 'bash /home/minecraft/classic/.start.sh'
```

Comment: thanks it worked i had the time wrong i didnt know i also have to do [Date] on the machine and follow that also what time whould i use to run a command every friday at 12am as soon as it turns friday and then another command at the end of sunday so 11:59 or whatever

Comment: Midnight on Friday would be `0 0 * * 5`; end of the day on Thursday would be `59 23 * * 4`.  If this answered your question, please accept.  Cheers!